# How to write formally and tersely that someone's work is utter nonsense and overly complicated?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

How to write formally and tersely that someone's work is utter nonsense and overly complicated?

Comment: You want a single formal word that means "your work is utterly nonsense and overly complicated than it should be"?

Comment: What does "overly complicated than it should be" mean?

Comment: You mean “utter nonsense” (not “utterly”). Utter is an adjective, which modifies a noun. Utterly is an adverb, so it can modify a verb or adjective. You could say something like “utterly appalling,” but not “utterly nonsense.”

Comment: Please read the [Help for this sort of question](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Why is "This is utter nonsense and overly complicated" not formal or terse enough? It seems to me it satisfies on both counts.

Comment: ***Nonsensical*** always sounds more "formal" than ***nonsense*** to me. But I think OP should be advised against trying to talk down to people in English until he knows the language a *lot* better, or he's likely to end up with egg on his face.

Comment: Don't write it at all. Be kind to your enemies on the way up; you may meet them again on the way down.

Comment: @KillingTime, yes, if possible.

Comment: @HotLicks Perhaps, I have exaggerated. I simply meant "overly complicated".

Comment: @JLG Thank you for the feedback. I appreciate it and updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thank you.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks :)

Comment: @Anton I agree with you. My intention is not to look down at someone's hard work. However, some pompous people who express their "simple" work with "too much sugar" makes me feel that something is not correct there. One who can't explain the work in simple words, it means to me that person has not understood good enough. This may be more philosphical than technical. Thank you for your comment though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the words you're looking for are [incoherent](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/incoherent) and [prolix](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prolix).

Comment: Thank you. Prolix is close to what I am looking for.